# how to split line at first period character based on word count and reiterate the process in resulting lines (in the pattern space)

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to split a text document where any line with more than 10 words (words defined as anything between whitespacees on both sides) should split at the first period character occurring from left to right. Any resulting lines with more than 10 words should also be split.

Sample Input Data:

```
1I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working.
2I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working.
3I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working more.
4I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working more.
5I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm sick.
6I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm so sick.
```

Desired Output Data:

```
1I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working.
2I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working.
3I got from Dr.
Smith, the OK to keep working more.
4I got from Dr.
Smith the O.K. to keep working more.
5I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm sick.
6I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K.
to keep working more, although I'm so sick.
```

I've tried the following code:

```
sed -r ':a; /((\w)+[., ]+){11}/s/\./\r\n/; ta' grab.txt | tr '\r' '.' > output.txt
```

The code produces the following inaccurate results:

```
1I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working.
2I got from Dr.
 Smith, the O.K. to keep working.
3I got from Dr.
 Smith, the OK to keep working more.
4I got from Dr.
 Smith, the O.K. to keep working more.
5I got from Dr.
 Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm sick.
6I got from Dr.
 Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm so sick.
```

Note line 1 and 2 both have 10 words, yet line 2 gets split (it seems like adding periods to a word ..eg. word O.K...makes it think there is more words in the line than there really are).

Note line 6 should actually be split in 3 because the second line has 11 words, yet for some reason it doesn't.

I'm looking for a solution that I can pipe into and out of.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't looked at trying to solve this at all, but there are more text-processing tools in *nix besides sed, and something more powerful (awk? perl?) might be a more appropriate tool for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `\w` is "word characters", which counts `O.K.` as two words, which doesn't match your definition of a word. I'd recommend looking into awk for this, as its default definition of a field is whitespace separated, which matches your use case well.

Comment: Why the line `4I got from Dr. Smith,` had not been splitted on 1st period in your desired output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest hey Roman, I don't think I quite  understand the question.

Comment: The desired output has the linebreak after `,` instead of the first `.`, which doesn't match what you say the desired output is.

Comment: @BenjaminW. ah, OK, I suspected as much. What is even odder then, is why isn't 2nd line of line6 being spitted. It should count as 12 words? Either way, I'm open to awk suggestion too...I tried but I don't know awk.

Comment: desired output presented as vague

Comment: @BenjaminW. maybe my eyes are tired, but which part of the code are you looking at?

Comment: We're talking about the *desired* output, where you have a linebreak after `4I got from Dr. Smith,`, but you say "split at the first period character occurring from left to right", which would be after `4I got from Dr.`.

Comment: ah yes I see. my eyes are tired! I edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec and your example of desired output don't match.

In particular, "words defined as anything between whitespacees on both sides" doesn't match

```
6I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.
K. to keep working more, although I'm so sick.`
```

Assuming your specification is right instead of your example, here's an all-bash solution:

```
while read -a line
do set -- "${line[@]}"
   cnt=${#@}
   while (( ${#@} ))
   do printf "%s " "$1";
      case "$1" in
      *.) if (( cnt > 10 ))
          then echo
               cnt=${#@}
          fi ;;
      esac
      shift
   done
   echo
done < grab.txt
```

Output:

```
1I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working.
2I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working.
3I got from Dr.
Smith, the OK to keep working more.
4I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K. to keep working more.
5I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K.
to keep working more, although I'm sick.
6I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K.
to keep working more, although I'm so sick.
```

If you just wanted to do it in `sed` -

```
$: cat tst
sed -E ':a
 /[.]*(\s+\S+){10,}/{
     s/[.]\s+/PLACEHOLDER\n/
     ta
 }
 s/PLACEHOLDER/. /g
' grab.txt
```

as one line:

```
$: sed -E ':a; /[.]*(\s+\S+){10,}/{ s/[.]\s+/PLACEHOLDER\n/;  ta; }; s/PLACEHOLDER/. /g;' grab.txt
```

Close enough?

Comment: `-E`, `\s`, `\S`, `+` these are all GNU extensions, and not all seds are GNU sed. And `printf "$1 "` will fail if `$1` has `%` in it, and you don't need `$` between `((` and `))`

Comment: Good points, thanks. If they are available, I use the GNU stuff, and they usually are. If not, we do it a different way.

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward solution with awk:

```bash
awk '{
  while (NF>10) {
    if (!(i=index($0,".")))
      break
    print substr($0,1,i)
    $0=substr($0,i+1)
    # trim leading blank(s)
    $1=$1
  }
  if ($0!="")
    print
}' file
```

As long as there are more than ten *words* in a line, it's split by the first *period* into two; the first part is printed, and the line is updated with the second part, and so on.

Doing this with sed btw, not a good idea at all.

Comment: this almost works, except for some files when I run this the actual file size keeps growing and growing unless I stop the process and close the terminal (it's almost like it's looping endlessly). I've been trying to figure out why for some files it works, but for others it keeps on looping. Also, does this part [$0=substr($0,i+1)] define the sentence as the remainder of what is not extracted? By the way, this inspired me to learn some basics of awk or some other programming language because sed is getting to convoluted to do what I need. Thanks for that !

Comment: @HenryM Oh I forgot to check i's value, updated the answer now. And yes, that part does that

Comment: Thanks. Great stuff. You really inspired me.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\S+(\s+\S+){10}/s/\.\s/.\n/;P;D' file
```

If the current line contains 11 or more words, replace the first period (and any trailing white space) by a period and a newline, print/delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: The code is very elegant, but it doesn't quite work...the 6th line at "O.K" gets split at the "O." instead of O.K. I would like whole words to stay together.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sed` command works for the input provided.

```
cat <<EOF |
1I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working.
2I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working.
3I got from Dr. Smith, the OK to keep working more.
4I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working more.
5I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm sick.
6I got from Dr. Smith, the O.K. to keep working more, although I'm so sick.
EOF
sed '
    # hold the whole line
    h

    :again

    /\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{9\}[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/{
        /\./!{
            s/.*/ERROR: no dot in pattern space to split ontu\nI have no idea what should I do here/
            p
            q
        }
        # add the newline behind dot in the hold space
        x
        # substitute first dot for a newline
        s/^\([^.]*\)\.[[:space:]]*/\1\n/
        x
        # remove everything before the dot in pattern space
        s///
        bagain
    }

    # ok, hold space has the result
    x
    # we removed dots from end of the lines
    # so we dont have to match them
    # restore them
    s/\x0a/.\n/g    
'
```

will output:

```
1I got from Dr.
Smith, the OK to keep working.
2I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K. to keep working.
3I got from Dr.
Smith, the OK to keep working more.
4I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.K. to keep working more.
5I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.
K. to keep working more, although I'm sick.
6I got from Dr.
Smith, the O.
K. to keep working more, although I'm so sick.
```

First I hold the whole line in hold space. The hold space will hold the result.

Then with `\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{9\}[^[:space:]]\{1,\}` I match 10 words - 10 groups of non-whitespaces characters separted by whitespaces. If there are any, I check if there is a dot in the line, because if there isn't, well, I don't know what should happen, I just exit.

If there is a dot, we substitute the dot for a newline in hold space. And remove the dot with everything in front of it in pattern space and start again.

If there are no more then 10 words in pattern space, that means we removed enough words in front of the dots. Because I have removed the dots in hold space, I need to restore them on each line ending.

And of course a oneliner:

```
sed 'h; :again; /\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{9\}[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/{ /\./!{ s/.*/ERROR/p; q}; x; s/^\([^.]*\)\.[[:space:]]*/\1\n/; x;  s///; bagain}; x; s/\x0a/.\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the detailed explanation. The code is insanely long :). I really need to start getting away from sed and looking into awk or some other options.